# Compile Spark stream kinesis sample application using SBT tool

Tags: scala, sbt, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to compile and create a jar for Spark kinesis stream scala application provided by spark itself in the given link. 
[Kinesis word count sample](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/external/kinesis-asl/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/KinesisWordCountASL.scala)

Following is my sbt file, It has all the dependencies and its compiling fine for simple programs.

```
name := "stream parser"

version := "1.0"

val sparkVersion = "2.0.2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core"  % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming"  % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql"  % sparkVersion % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl"  % sparkVersion % "provided"
)
```

But the kinesis sample throwing following error while compiling in my Ubuntu system.

```
trait Logging in package internal cannot be accessed in package org.apache.spark.internal
[error] object KinesisWordCountASL extends Logging {
[error]                                    ^
```

Logging class import

```
import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging
```

Any Idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: what sbt version are using ?

Comment: `[info] This is sbt 0.13.12
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.6
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.6`

Comment: New finding : when I build for spark version 1.4.1 its working . with some modification in code like `import org.apache.spark.Logging` instead of `import org.apache.spark.internal.Logging`

Comment: Did you ever make progress with this?  I'm seeing the same issue.  I have tried multiple versions.

Answer (score 0):

According to spark repo 2.0 and above Logging class is included in `package org.apache.spark.internal` [spark](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.0.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/Logging.scala) In previous releases it is in `package org.apache.spark` I'd suggest run your example setting up spark 2.0.0 or later. Or make changes according usage of appropiate libraries.

Same example with build.sbt is compiling without any issues

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.0.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kinesis-asl" % "2.0.2",
  "com.amazonaws" % "amazon-kinesis-producer" % "0.10.2"
)
```

Comment: I was using the org.apache.spark.internal.Logging only for the spark 2.0.0 or later. Still its throwing the mentioned error.

Comment: Try use instead of `provided` scope `compile`